# Groovy - Unable to use static final string in an annotation

Tags: groovy

Something is really wierd.
I'm using a static final String in an annotation value.

```
class Constants {
    static final String myConstant = "ting tong"   
}

class Service {
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = Constants.myConstant)
    void doSomethingNice() {    
    }
}
```

However, i just cant get it to compile.

Here's the error message

> Attribute 'myConstant' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found
>   type 'java.lang.Object' in
>   @org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict
>
> Expected 'Constants.getMyConstant()' to be an inline constant of type
>   java.lang.String in @org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict

What can be the problem? This works perfectly in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was due to the automatic getter/setter generation of Groovy. It would generate a getter for my constant and use it within the annotation, and i guess thats not allowed.

To fix, mark the field as public. That would disable the automatic getter generation.

```
class Constants {
    public static final String myConstant = "ting tong"   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add a ```static```keyword in there somewhere? Without the ```static``` keyword on the declaration of ```myConstant```, it is an *instance variable*. Thus it would be impossible to access it with the *class variable* notation```Constant.myConstant``` in either Java or Groovy.

Comment: @BalRog oh yes. sorry. i DID have the static keyword in my class. Forgot to mention it. Updated the answer and question

Comment: You don't need the `public` keyword. `public` is default in Groovy.

Comment: @BalRog Yes. You don't. But marking the field as public disables the getter/setter generation. If it is not public, the field "acts" like a public field via the getters and setters

Answer (score 5):

In general it is a good practice to keep the constants under an Interface and not under class.

```
interface Constants {
    public static final String myConstant = "ting tong"   
}
```

Another good practice is to define constants as **static final** not just final, because it is more efficient to create only 1 instance for each constant.

Comment: thanks for the advice about the interface. i actually did have static in my code. Just forgot to mention it correctly in the question.